# Think I found a bug in PHP v5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I may have found a bug, if so who do I report this too?

Here is what I've got:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= ($count)-1; ++$i) {
 Lots of code...more then I want to put here
....
.....
.....
$mailto = $mailto . $i +1 . ") " . $name . " " . $location . " Type: " . $type . " Status: " . $geostatus . " Difficulty " .$difficulty . "\n" . $region . "\nHidden: " . $hidden . " Last Update: " . $lastupdate . " Last Found: " . $lastfound . "\nDistance: $distance Bearing: $bearing degrees $direction\n\n";
}

echo "$mailto \n";
```

The output will look like this:

```
4) Morrow Parking - RR Relic LMBT Lat: 39.35455 Lon: -84.133733 Type: Traditional Cache Status: Active Difficulty 3
City/State: Morrow, OH Warren Co.
Hidden: Wed June 09 2010 04:00 Last Update: Wed August 03 2011 17:43 Last Found: Wed December 31 1970 19:00
Distance: 4.31 Bearing: 212 degrees SW
```

Showing me only the last item in the list.
However if I change the code just slightly to this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= ($count)-1; ++$i) {
 Lots of code...more then I want to put here
....
.....
.....
$cc = $i +1;
$mailto = $mailto . $cc . ") " . $name . " " . $location . " Type: " . $type . " Status: " . $geostatus . " Difficulty " .$difficulty . "\n" . $region . "\nHidden: " . $hidden . " Last Update: " . $lastupdate . " Last Found: " . $lastfound . "\nDistance: $distance Bearing: $bearing degrees $direction\n\n";
}

echo "$mailto \n";
```

I get the full output as I expect to see:

```
1) Uranus - The Solar System - Lil Miami Bike Trail Lat: 39.415517 Lon: -84.103383 Type: Traditional Cache Status: Active Difficulty 1.5
City/State: , OH Warren Co.
Hidden: Sun October 17 2010 04:00 Last Update: Fri August 05 2011 18:25 Last Found: Wed December 31 1970 19:00
Distance: 0.92 Bearing: 309 degrees NW

2) 79 Lat: 39.394517 Lon: -84.096533 Type: Traditional Cache Status: Active Difficulty 2
City/State: , OH Warren Co.
Hidden: Sun May 30 2010 04:00 Last Update: Wed August 03 2011 17:42 Last Found: Wed December 31 1970 19:00
Distance: 0.93 Bearing: 201 degrees S

3) RR Relic - Oregonia Lat: 39.462583 Lon: -84.100383 Type: Traditional Cache Status: Active Difficulty 1.5
City/State: Oregonia, OH Warren Co.
Hidden: Sun May 02 2010 04:00 Last Update: Wed August 03 2011 17:41 Last Found: Wed December 31 1970 19:00
Distance: 3.88 Bearing: 351 degrees N

4) Morrow Parking - RR Relic LMBT Lat: 39.35455 Lon: -84.133733 Type: Traditional Cache Status: Active Difficulty 3
City/State: Morrow, OH Warren Co.
Hidden: Wed June 09 2010 04:00 Last Update: Wed August 03 2011 17:43 Last Found: Wed December 31 1970 19:00
Distance: 4.31 Bearing: 212 degrees SW
```

Did I find a bug, or am I doing something wrong in the 1st way, and correct in the 2nd way?

And if I did find a bug, who do I report it too.

PHP v5.3.3 running CLI version on Ubuntu 10.10 Thanks.

Comment: sounds trivial... but did you try `$mailto . ($i + 1) .`

Answer (score 2):

In the first bit of code, change:

```
$mailto = $mailto . $i +1 . ") " . $name . " " . $location . " Type: " . $type . " Status: " . $geostatus . " Difficulty " .$difficulty . "\n" . $region . "\nHidden: " . $hidden . " Last Update: " . $lastupdate . " Last Found: " . $lastfound . "\nDistance: $distance Bearing: $bearing degrees $direction\n\n";
```

to

```
$mailto = $mailto . ($i +1) . ") " . $name . " " . $location . " Type: " . $type . " Status: " . $geostatus . " Difficulty " .$difficulty . "\n" . $region . "\nHidden: " . $hidden . " Last Update: " . $lastupdate . " Last Found: " . $lastfound . "\nDistance: $distance Bearing: $bearing degrees $direction\n\n";
```

I suspect you're just getting the order of operations wrong.

Comment: Specifically, concatenating a string with an integer `($mailto . $i)` works but probably isn't your intent.  However, adding a non-numeric string and an integer treats the string as 0.

Comment: Ok, that does give me the output I expect to see. Thanks for that...saves on a little bit of extra stuff in there! :-)  So my next question would it not still be a bug because $i is my counter for the loop -

Comment: No, it's not a bug, just you mucking up the order of operations and type casting. You are doing `$mailto . $i`, then adding 1 to that. As you're adding an int to a string, the string gets converted to an int (zero) before it's added to `$i`. That's why you're seeing just the results for `$i` when it is 4 - you've turned all the previous output into `0`.

Comment: OK....Thanks for explaining that...that make since to me... I see what you are saying now...well, good I didn't find a bug, bad I didn't know what I was doing LOL Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with operator precedence. Here's a simplified example:

```
$i=1;// doesn't matter what this value is
$s = " alpha " . $i+1 .  " beta " . " gamma<br>\n";
echo $s; // 1 beta gamma

$s = " alpha " . ($i+1) .  " beta " . " gamma<br>\n";
echo $s; // alpha 2 beta gamma
```

The odd behavior in the first case even happens if you cat the addition to an (int).

```
$s = " alpha " . (int)$i+1 .  " beta " . " gamma<br>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks all of the info, my wife is in a math class, she is always asking me about the order of operations, guess I should learn to listen to myself. OK good I didn't find a bug, bad I just don't know what I am doing...thanks for the help.